# SSRS passing multi-value parameters to open report in additional window

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, sqlreportingservice

We've created a report with Report Builder, published to the report server.  Report 1, the primary report has 6 parameters; 3 multi-value params and 3 single value params.  Would like Report 2 to open from Report 1 but in a separate window and pass all 6 parameters.  In Report 2, they are also built as parameters.  Parameters:
Neighborhood (multi)
Start (single)
End(single)
Source (multi)
Data_type(multi)
Prov_type(single)

In Report 1 we've created a text box with an action to open a javascript command.  Here's the current call in Report 1 that opens another window but gives the generic error "not valid"

`javascript:void(window.open('http://ourcompany/Reportserver/Pages/Report.aspx?%2fReports+in+Development%2funknown+provider+detail&rs:Command=Render&NEIGHBORHOOD="+join(Parameters!NEIGHBORHOOD.Value, "&NEIGHBORHOOD=")&"&SOURCE="+join(Parameters!SOURCE.Value,"&SOURCE=")&"&DATA_TYPE="+join(Parameters!DATA_TYPE.Value,"&DATA_TYPE=")&"&START="+Fields!START.Value+"&END="+Fields!END.Value+"&PROV_TYPE="+Fields!PROV_TYPE.Value+"'))`

I've replaced "Fields" with "Parameters" and it still doesn't work.  If I created it passing static fields it works as seen below;

`javascript:void(window.open('http://ourcompany/Reportserver/Pages/Report.aspx?%2fReports+in+Development%2funknown+provider+detail&rs:Command=Render&rc:Parameters=true&NEIGHBORHOOD=Mesa&START=11/01/2016'))`

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using (in textbox properties >>action tab "Go to report")?

Comment: Yes, and it works however it opens in the same window.  Would like the report to open in its own window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you are passing in the multi-value parameters multiple times. For example, part of your expression would result in:

```
...&SOURCE=A&SOURCE=B&SOURCE=C...
```

You can only set one value per parameter in the URL.

So the solution to that would be to comma separate the values and pass them in as a single string. Then, in the subreport, you would need to parse them out again.

```
"&SOURCE=" & join(Parameters!SOURCE.Value,",")
```

You may run into additional issues such as URL length limitations, but this will fix the immediate problem.

Comment: I changed the code as you stated above and received the same error rsInvalidItemPath. "&SOURCE="+join(Parameters!SOURCE.Value,",")

Comment: Specific error " '/Reports in Development/unknown provider detail,join(Parameters!NEIGHBORHOOD.Value, ","),",join(Parameters!SOURCE.Value,","),",join(Parameters!DATA_TYPE.Value,","),"' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. (rsInvalidItemPath) "

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've worked out the syntax and believe that is working.  I took out a few extra ampersands I had in there.  Here's the code working:

```
javascript:void(window.open('http://ourcompany/Reportserver/Pages/Report.aspx?%2fReports+in+Development%2funknown+provider+detail&rs:Command=Render&NEIGHBORHOOD="+join(Parameters!NEIGHBORHOOD.Value, ",")"&SOURCE="+join(Parameters!SOURCE.Value,",")"&DATA_TYPE="+join(Parameters!DATA_TYPE.Value,",")"&START="+Parameters!START.Value+"&END="+Parameters!END.Value+"&PROV_TYPE="+Parameters!PROV_TYPE.Value+"'))
```

However, I have an entirely different issue now.  Looks like an SSRS bug.  I get the error, "report parameter 'START' is not valid for its type. (rsReportParameterTypeMismatch)" In both reports they are date/time values. I've done all the tricks by changing the system datetime formats to no avail.  Any thoughts on this one?  Thanks